# Oracle 11g impdp and expdp issue

Tags: oracle

I used `expdp user1\user1@orcl DUMPFILE=user.dmp` for exporting.

The export was success.

but when i tried on another oracle 11 DB to import 
`impdp user2\user2 DUMPFILE=user.dmp` it start to search for user1 and try to import in that user1

I want to import that in user2. Can anyone help.

i cannot create a network_link , as i get this file from a another vendor which will not provide be rights to a network link but i need to import his dmp file in another user in my database

Answer (score 1):

Use `remap_schema` parameter to import data to other schema. The use is simple: `remap_schema=old_name:new_name`.

To import to another database you need to use `network_link` parameter. But before that, you need to add entry in your `tnsnames.ora`, for example:

```
 imphost =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = /*PUT ADDRESS HERE*/)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = /*PUT SERVICE NAME HERE*/)
    )
  )
```

Next, connect to your database and create database link with `CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK imphost USING 'imphost'`. Now you should run you should run `impdp dumpfile=user.dmp network_link=imphost remap_schema=user1:user2` - I never tried that before, so it's only a guess based on [this article](http://a2zakir.blogspot.com/2012/02/expdp-exporting-to-remote-server-using.html).

Comment: i want to export from one database and import in another database and there is no DB link in middle

Comment: Updated the answer. I never used `network_link` and public database links, so it might not work. I miss-looked that part of your question @parveen

Comment: i cannot create a network_link as i get this file from a another vendor which will not provide be rights to a network link but i need to import his dmp file in another user

Comment: vendor uses expdp comment to export dump file and i need to import the dmp file he provide into another user